# Xamarin не работает после установки

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, install

Установил Xamarin в VS 2017. Создаю проект Cross Platform App > Пустое приложение > Xamarin.Forms > PLC.
В итоге вылезают предупреждения:

[image: скрин]

Как исправить это? При дебаге ошибка построения появляется

Comment: Ошибки только с Android? Если зайти в установщик - есть предупреждения? SDK проверяли?

Comment: @Dev, проблемы только с Android. Пытаюсь исправлять их - другие поялвяются

Comment: ну если что новое появиться в ошибках, делайте скрины. А так в первую очередь надо смотреть SDK Manager, стоит ли там минимум для создания приложения. Бывает что драйвер на эмулятор не ставиться, так как виртуализация в биосе отключена

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте очистить решение, а потом пересобрать его.

Иногда помогает перенос папки проекта в корень диска С или D, т.е. проблема в длинном пути к проекту.

Самое страшное, что может быть это несовместимость версий библиотек  устанавливаемых по умолчанию в проект (у меня так было в VS2015). Понижение версии одной из библиотек (к сожалению не помню какой) помогало. Сейчас создавая проект основная часть библиотек Xamarin.Android версии 25.4.0.2, а Xamarin.Forms 2.4.0.280

Comment: 1 и 2 уже пробовал, не помогло. Попробую пошаманить с версиями библиотек

Comment: Какие у меня версии библиотек я написал, еще проверь путь и версию jdk у меня 1.8.0_131 (это в параметрах VS - Xamarin - Параметры Android), ну и пути Android SDK и NDK, как советовали выше. Странно, в VS2017 у меня таких проблем не было, может попробовать обновить VS или вообще Xamarin переустановить (но это конечно зависит от того на сколько давно все ставилось).

Answer (score 0):

1. Так же иногда приходится удалять папки bin и obj из всех проектов,
2. перезагрузить студию и иногда даже компьютер.
3. Некоторые варнинги так и будут мозолить глаз, главное знать что ошибка не в коде.
4. Если проект на Андроиде то для дебага: правой кнопкой по Андроид проекту-> Options->Android Options, там должно быть **выбрано** Use Shared Runtime, и **отключено** Use Fast Deployment
5. Ах да иногда не с первого раза проект собирается. Но к счастью Xamarin развивается и таких багов становиться все меньше и меньше.